# Pandas indexing breaks with timezone aware timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

Using iloc to access a single column of timezone aware timestamps in a dataframe breaks in some obscure manner returning the value not the row containing it.

Taking a single element dataframe containing one timestamp. If there is no timezone iloc operates as expected...

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[parser.parse('2018-05-01T12:00:00')]})
a.iloc[0]['A']
```

If there is a timezone somehow iloc[0] returns the actual timestamp not the row containing it resulting the ['A'] trying to subscript the timestamp itself...

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[parser.parse('2018-05-01T12:00:00+00:00')]})
a.iloc[0]['A']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ef1b8153d3ca> in <module>()
      1 a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[parser.parse('2018-05-01T12:00:00+00:00')]})
----> 2 a.iloc[0]['A']

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
```

This is an oddity confined to dataframes containing only one column, adding another column containing anything restores the normal behaviour of iloc.

In this case reversing the order of row/column addressing results in the correct behaviour...

```
a['A'].iloc[0]
```

Very tempted to call this a bug.

Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Pandas version 0.22
Numpy 1.14.0
Dateutil 2.6.1

Same behaviour under linux (redhat)
With pandas version 0.20.3
Numpy 1.13.1
Dateutil 2.6.1

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce. Any particularities on what you're running? system, etc?

Comment: @erasmortg - Hmm, I've added more info as to my setup, how does your's compare? (and thank you for trying!)

Comment: I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 16.10 Python 2.7.12, Pandas 0.18.1, Numpy 1.14.2, Dateutil 2.6.1

Comment: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0, Python 3.6.1, pandas 0.22.0, 1.12.1, dateutil 2.6.0